# Datepicker does not work properly in modal where html is returned using jQuery .load()

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-datepicker

I am working in VS2017 MVC (v5.2.3.0), using Bootstrap (v3.3.7) and the jQuery (v2.2.4) .load() function to load HTML into the bootstrap modal. After the modal is loaded the datepicker does not function as expected. It will work properly if I load the modal into the DOM at page load, but not after the DOM is created.

I am currently using datepicker for bootstrap v1.6.4.  I have tried updating to the latest: v1.8.0 - No difference.

**Actual behaviour**

The datepicker gets initialized however the selected date never gets set as the input value - it just remains blank.

**Example code**

```
//Modal partial html (only showing the HTML Helper for simplicity)

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FollowUpDate,
new
{
    data_input = "followup-date",
    data_datepicker_short_date = "",
    data_val = "true",
    data_val_required = "Follow Up Date is required.",
    @class = "datepicker"
})


//Initialize datepicker in modal partial as followed

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#FollowUpDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        autoclose: true,
        startDate: new Date('@String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyy}", DateTime.Now.AddDays(m))'),
        endDate: new Date('@String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyy}", DateTime.Now.AddDays(p-1))')
    });
});
```

Cannot set a date:
I can click any date, including navigating the datepicker month and year buttons, however the datepicker just stays the same - not even closing unless I click outside the datepicker.

[Datepicker in modal after jQuery load function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cQfj.png)

Here is my jQuery .load function where I am initializing the datepicker, which it does, but when I select a date it does not display, or sometimes the date appears then disappears quickly.

```
$(modal.modalId + ' .modal-content').load(modal.getURL, function () {
    $('#FollowUpDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        autoclose: true,
    });
});
```

Comment: You need to initialize the datepicker after the html has been added to the DOM (in the success callback)

Comment: Thanks, but I have already tried that approach and it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Then clearly you did not do it correctly

Comment: I have added my jquery load method to show what I am doing. If this is not correct please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved. The issue was due to data loading into the modal via the 'show.bs.modal' event, and the bootstrap datepicker inside the modal, calling the same event. The resulting behavior was the modal data would get refreshed each time you set focus to the datepicker. To fix this problem, I just needed to unbind the modal event after it was called.